# The fastest datetime serialization/deserialization with full precision in Python JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, serialization

What is the fastest datetime serialization/deserialization with full precision in Python JSON?

I prepare some code to test the best solution and prepared some solution and what ask you if you know better solution (faster).

```
import datetime
import timeit
import json

# date ready to serialize
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

def date_tuple():
  x = (d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.minute, d.second, d.microsecond)
  y = json.dumps(x)
  z = json.loads(y)
  b = datetime.datetime(*z)
  # this is check if precision is same
  if d != b:
    raise ValueError(d-b)

# check speed of operation
print timeit.timeit(date_tuple, number=1000)
```

Comment: You could save the `timestamp` and the `microsecond` field and restore the result with `fromtimestamp` and `replace(microsecond=..)`.  However there may be some edge cases were this fails to return the exact same time.